# Reservation system,dynamic <select> tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello I am building a private apartment reservation system. I am stuck at giving the user the option of selecting multiple rooms of the same type. What I am trying to do is use < select > that will contain IDs of rooms selected.
This is my database structure:
**Reservation table:**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| id   checkin    checkout   room_id  guestname  partysize |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1   2017-01-01  2017-01-10    1       somename    2      |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Rooms table**

```
+------------------------------------------+
| id      name     price  accomodationsize |
+------------------------------------------+
| 1    doubleroom   50        2            |
+------------------------------------------+
```

This is the query from index.php for retrieving available rooms in the selected time period:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'search')
{
    include '../includes/db.inc.php';
    try
    {
        $sql ='SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE rooms.id NOT IN
               (SELECT rooms.id FROM rooms
                LEFT JOIN reservation
                ON rooms.id = reservation.room_id WHERE
                checkin BETWEEN :checkin AND :checkout OR
                checkout BETWEEN :checkin AND :checkout OR
                checkin AND checkout BETWEEN :checkin AND :checkout)';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':checkin',$_POST['checkin']);
        $s->bindValue(':checkout',$_POST['checkout']);
        $s->execute();
    }
```

This query is then used in the following code (I switched `$s` to `$rooms_id`) This code tries to give the user the option of selecting multiple rooms from the same form depending on what the SQL query returned. I tried using `<select>` tag like this( I know the following code is messy and contains alot of things that dont make sense but I have been testing on it a lot to try to figure out the problem):

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
              <select name="optname">
                  <option value="default">0</option>
                  <?php foreach($rooms_id as $id):?>
                  <?php $selectedrooms[] = $id; ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $selectedrooms?>">
                        <?php print_r($selectedrooms); ?>
                    </option>
                  <?php endforeach;?>
              </select>
              <input type="submit" name="action" value="reserve">
          </form>
```

I thought this would send the `<select>` back to my index.php and I would use this info to do a `INSERT` query into the reservation table. But that does not happen. After using `$_POST['optname']`,`var_dump` shows a STRING that says 'Array' instead of the actual array with ID values.

EDIT:

This is where the `$_POST['action']` and `$_POST['action'] == 'search'` is being used.

```
<?php 
include '../includes/header.html.php';
?>
    <body>
        <div id="formcontainer">
           <form action="index.php" method="post">
                   <p>Check-in:</p>
                    <input type="date" name="checkin" required>
                    <br>
                    <p>Check-out:</p>
                    <input type="date" name="checkout" required>
                    <br>
                    <p>Number of guests:</p>
                    <input type="number" name="partysize" required>
                    <br>
               <input type="submit" name="action" value="search">
           </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$_POST['action'] == 'search'` that failed and nowhere do I see where you're using a POST array for the `<select>`'s name.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using, mysql or mssql? you tagged as both here

Comment: I think you're looking for `if(isset($_POST['optname']))` instead of `if(isset($_POST['action']))`.

Comment: there's also no matching name attribute for your `$_POST['checkin']` and `$_POST['checkout']`.

Comment: What do you mean  $_POST['action'] == 'search'? Thats the value from submit that a user fills out to get the rooms that are available. That way I am  checking if the form has been submitted, I don't think it failed but I am not sure what do you mean. $_POST of the select is used in index.php I can add the code if you want but I dont think thats the problem it basically just:<?php  
$some123 = $_REQUEST['optname'];
var_dump($some123);
;?>

Comment: now where pray tell do you see `value="search"`??

Comment: Sorry for that,I am using MySql, ObsidanAge that check if the form where the user select his checkin/ checkout date has been submitted so that is fine. I can add that part of the code if you think it helps but I dont think it's relevant

Comment: I added the edit for "search".

Comment: your question was almost closed as a duplicate; next time. **please** post your code relative to what it's about and not something we have to guess if it's used elsewhere.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query